# Using Redis as main database in production

Tags: redis

I have used Redis before in many projects, usually as a temporary cache, or to share small pieces of data between different subsystems. you get the idea. But now, I'm building a service that mainly revolves around the concept of a key-value store and needs super-fast data retrieval, so I'm using Redis. And because of this, all my data would be on Redis (it's not just a temporary cache or something of that sort). So I'm wondering, is this OK or should I take backups to another more "stable" database like MongoDB or MySQL?

Note that I'm not talking about the usual periodic backups. I would do that regardless of what database I end up using.

Comment: Did you check Redis Cloud? It's based on Redis Enterprise and is used by many users as their main DB when low latency is required.

Comment: @GuyKorland I'm familiar with it, but I don't know if using Redis as main database and for somewhat large data is common. Do you know of any large service that does this?